# Node.js -- Undefined:0 Syntax Error: Unexpected end of input

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js, backbone.js

Just getting my feet wet with Node.js and Backbone.js. I'm using the book "Backbone Blueprints" and some of the code he provides to set up the webserver appears to not work.

I have Node.js installed and running (I know this works). His package.json code seemed to do the trick, but I'll post it below just in case:

```
{
  "name": "simple-blog",
  "description": "This is a simple blog.",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "3.x.x",
    "ejs": "~0.8.4",
    "bourne": "0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "latest"
  }
}
```

This is the server.js code that errors out when I try to turn on the server:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var Bourne = require("bourne");

var app = express();
var posts = new Bourne("simpleBlogPosts.json");
var comments = new Bourne("simpleBlogComments.json");

app.configure(function(){
    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});

app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
    res.render("index.ejs");
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Full error:

```
> nodemon server.js

11 Mar 19:35:22 - [nodemon] v1.3.7
11 Mar 19:35:22 - [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
11 Mar 19:35:22 - [nodemon] watching: *.*
11 Mar 19:35:22 - [nodemon] starting `node server.js`
undefined:0

^
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
    at Object.parse (native)
    at new Bourne (C:\Users\MyName\WebstormProjects\simpleBlog\node_modules\bou
rne\lib\bourne.js:52:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\MyName\WebstormProjects\simpleBlog\server.j
s:6:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

I did digging before I decided to post this question. Comments elsewhere indicate this can happen if you're attempting to use an undefined/empty variable or if you're missing a '{' somewhere.

That doesn't appear to be the case with this code, and this is literally straight out of the book.

Webstorm does note that the app.configure function has an 'invalid number of arguments' and that it is 'expecting 2'.

The book itself is not old at all, having come out in 2014.

Just in case: this is not a 'homework' question, I'm trying to teach myself Backbone.js and it just so happens the technologies this author chose to facilitate that learning quest consisted of Node.js and Express among others.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you include the contents of `simpleBlogPosts.json`?

Comment: By the error message, it seems the problem is in the JSON files you are making Bourne read.

Comment: @phihag, 

it's blank. I believe these were procedurally generated. 

If this were inherently an issue, why would the author say this:

"Actually, at this point, you can run npm start on the command line and open up http://localhost:3000 in a browser. You'll get an error because we haven't made the view template file yet, but you can see that our server is working."

I should note I went ahead and created the view file he specified, and placed it where appropriate, and nothing happened.

Comment: Did you actually create an empty `simpleBlogPosts.json` file? It's a JSON file, so if it is there and empty, then it isn't valid JSON and will throw. Looks like Bourne will create it properly if it isn't there, but by having it there and empty, Bourne errors out. That is the error message you get from `JSON.parse('')`

Comment: I didn't create it, but the file exists because it was automatically made by Bourne. 

How could this application work if the whole thing implodes if a file it creates itself is blank? Wouldn't this be the sort of thing that the book would address and say "Oh, if you try to turn on your server after doing everything I told you the whole thing will error out at the command line"?

Comment: So if you delete it, it adds it back as blank? It should add it as valid JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that bourne expects `simpleBlogPosts.json` to contain a valid JSON document, but the file does not.

Simply deleting `simpleBlogPosts.json` and restarting the server should be enough to generate a valid JSON file, i.e. with contents `[]`. Most likely, you need to do the same with `simpleBlogComments.json`.